# netbeans 7.3.1 no options under code formatting

Tags: netbeans, code-formatting, netbeans-7.3

I have just installed Netbeans 7.3.1 under GNU/Linux, Archlinux kernel version: arch-pc 3.10.10-1-ARCH x86_64

I have activated the PHP plugin and i want to setup the formatting options, for this I'm going to Tools->Options->Editor->Formatting, but the problem is that in here I have no code to select and setup the formatting, can this be a bug or I am doing something wrong?

This is how it looks when i get there:

[image: Netbeans 7.3.1 no formatting options]

The list under Language: has options Item 1 to Item 4 and the same for Category: Item 1 to Item 4.

Comment: I can confirm the problem, also under Arch Linux with kernel 3.10.10-1-ARCH (32bit). Can anybody reproduces this on a different system? Maybe we have a bug here, but I couldn´t find any bug reports yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution:

1. Go to: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/editor-formatting-screencast.html
2. Download the zip under:  [NetBeans Sample Code Library](https://netbeans.org/projects/samples/downloads/download/Samples/Java/Formatting.zip)
3. Import project: *File>Import Project>From zip...*
4. Go to *Tools>Options>Editor>Formatting* and you have the settings back

I do not know why it worked but it worked. Hope that this will help you.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I was able to bring the option back up was to go to a deactivated language (PHP in my case) and click the button to activate it to get the available options.

After doing this, I clicked back on the "Formatting" tab and the options were all there again.

Comment: This worked for me too, whereas the accepted solution did not. I had to close+reopen NetBeans after activating the language though.

Comment: Turns out it was a temporary fix. Now I've only got the "Enable C++" button to repeat it with...

Comment: This worked for me.  I enabled PHP support (I now have Java, PHP, and C++ enabled) and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Just enable Java SE plugin (tools - options - java - enable). You can then set formatting options for all languages (not only Java).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on arch linux 64bit. My solution is to install netbeans-cpp from AUR -- this version works, but hasn't other languages.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with C++. This fixed it: Tools > Plugins > Installed > Click check box: "C/C++" > Activate.  Now recheck editor formatting options.